# Trying to catch an exception

Tags: java, try-catch

Basically I would like the code to catch the exception if the person enters a number instead of a letter /name. the program is running however it does not catch when you enter a number instead of letter

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ITFINAL 

{

  public static void main(String []args)

  {

   String role;
   String name;

   try

   {

    role = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input" + e, "",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
   }
   System.exit(0);

  }
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: This code as is should not throw an exception, isn't it?

Comment: You'll need to add some logic, to check for numbers, and any other characters that you consider invalid.  Think carefully about what characters _should_ be allowed - don't forget things like apostrophes, hyphens, dots (Harry S. Truman) and so on.

Comment: Why do you want to throw an exception?  The code collecting the input and the error handling is happening in the same method, so you can just use standard conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
role = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name");
```

Will **never** throw an exception as is, because `showInputDialog("...")` returns a **string**. Therefore, even if the user enters `42`, the value you get is the **string** `"42"`.

Now to check whether the string is an integer, one way of doing so is using a regular expression:

```
if(role.matches("-?\\d+")) {
    throw new InputMismatchException(); //throw your exception
}
```

However, like others mentioned in the comments, why would you throw an exception and then handle it in the `catch` block? You could directly display an error message from inside the above `if` statement like so, without throwing any exception:

```
if(role.matches("-?\\d+")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input", "",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```